# Clearing state after render

Tags: reactjs, state, higher-order-components

Consider this HOC I use for fetching data

```
function withData(Component, endpoint) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      result: null,
      loading: false,
      error: { state: false, msg: '' }
    };

    fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/${this.props.params || ''}`);
        this.setState(state => ({ result: response.data, loading: !state.loading }));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error caugh in withData HOC', err);
        this.setState({ error: true });
      }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.params !== prevProps.params) {
        this.fetchData();
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { result, loading } = this.state;
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (!result) return null;

      return <Component result={result} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

You will notice I am saying if `!result` do not render the component. The problem is when `this.props.params` to this component changes, `this.state.result` is preserving the value of the older state. I want to reset result to null after each render, so it behaves the exact same as the initial render.

How can I achieve this?

To make it more clear, it would be great if I could do this in `componentWillUnmount` so that it's ready for the next Component lifecycle. However the component never unmounts.

Please note, it must be done in the HOC and not in the Component it returns.

Comment: Do you want to reset `result` after each render, or every time you fetch new data? It looks to me like all you need to do is set `result` to `null` in `fetchData` at the same time you set `loading` to `true`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem with that is that render runs before `fetchData` meaning result will not be null when the params props change causing one extra render to `Component`

Comment: You'll have that re-render anyway, since `loading` is changing to `true`

Comment: Yes but that returns `<p>Loading...</p>;` and not the `<Component />` I want it to have the same behaviour as the initial time `withData` is called for all subsequent calls.

Comment: To make it more clear, it would be great if I could do this in `componentWillUnmount` so that it's ready for the next Component lifecycle

Comment: I posted the correct answer....

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Sorry to abandon you, but it was 3 AM and I realised I wasn't thinking straight ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you'll want your component (rendered by the HOC) to accept a key option, which will be the params props in my case.

Usually you use those for lists, but it can be used here as well. When a key is used, if it changes instead of updating, it will make a new instance of the component. That would mean you would not need the componentDidUpdate anymore.

You can read more about the bahavior here https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key