# Can I force react component to remount from inside that component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simply put, I want to remount a component if the URL receives a `remount` query in the URL. Unfortunately after googling, I couldn't really find much on forcing a component remount. I want it to completely remount so that the state gets wiped clean.

My goal is to do something like this:

```
if (remountQueryExists) {
    force component to remount somehow
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clearing state after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615209/clearing-state-after-render)

Comment: You just need to change the component's key - see: https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e